# How to pull from one remote branch to another branch in git?

Tags: git, github

For safety reason, my supervisor doesn't allow me to pull his work directly from the master branch. So I created one branch remotely named 'subbranch' and clone it to my local repository. How could I let 'subbranch' keep up to date with the master branch? I just know how to use the GUI to do it. How to do it with command line?

Comment: You could always fetch the original repo and then `reset --hard` to it on your local clone of `subbranch`.

Comment: It is not clear what you intend to do. How is updating a 'subbranch' with 'master' prevent you from 'pulling his work directly from the master branch'?
Can you describe how you are doing this with GUI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have not done it already clone the repository from master and then create a local branch in your clone, tracking to your upstream branch. For example

```
git clone https://github.com/rgulia/myclone
cd myclone
git checkout -b subbranch origin/subbranch
```

When you need to work in your clone, make sure you are on your branch.

```
git branch  # your current branch is highlighted with a '*'
```

Work on your branch normally, by committing changes to your branch. 
Push changes to your remote branch.

```
git commit
git push origin subbranch
```

From time to time you want to update with the changes from master

```
git fetch                  # get the changes from the remote repository. 
git merge master           # merge them into your branch
git push origin subbranch  # push your changes upstream
```

The git fetch applies to all branches, including master. The git merge creates a commit in your branch. Since you always work in your branch, you never commit nor push to master.

You might have to resolve conflicts. See this excellent tutorial. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html#mergeconflict

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> git branch --set-upstream-to remote-branch  # to track your local branch with remote branch
>
> git pull --rebase # to get the latest changes of remote branch

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

I'm assuming two branches master and demo.Merge Master code to demo
Step 1
A.go to the master->git checkout Master.
B.pull all the new changes from Master branch.
Step 2
A. now got to demo branch->git checkout demo
Step 3
A.merge the changes of Master branch into Demo branch
git merge Master 
B.Then push your updated code to git
git push origin demo